# How to know from which youtube video description link the person joined my telegram channel?

Tags: youtube, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a youtube channel on which I make educational videos and I also have a telegram channel to share study material, I mentioned my telegram channel link to my every youtube videos in discription box..

Now I want to know is their any method to find out from which youtube video that a person joined by telegram channel?

Please let me know in answers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.